# google maps javascript api v3: check whether direction/route is crossing a polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon, direction

is there a way to determine, whether a direction/route offered by google maps is going through a self-made polygon on the map? I was not able to find a particular function in the v3 javascript library description.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, I thought do it in script: take the array of Lgt Ltd generate by user with Direction Route class and compare with a "polygon" Lgt ltd.

Comment: check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035250/query-in-a-geometry-column-created-by-kml-file