# Query in a geometry column (created by kml file)?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-fusion-tables

If you query with

> contains ignore case

then the query will return the data, but does so slowly.

How I can query in a geometry column in a fusion table?

I created a kml file with Google Maps, which was imported to Google fusion table. When I try to search the longitude & latitude in the column `geometry` to return the names of the zones where longitude & latitude match in one or more points inside the polyline.

The geometry column in my case stores a polyline like this:

Current cell value:

```
<LineString><coordinates>
-99.832771,16.88472,0.0
-99.832703,16.88558,0.0
-99.832703,16.88558,0.0
-99.831383,16.885441,0.0 
..... 
</coordinates></LineString>
```

Now I try query `tableid = 3427749`:

```
http://fusiontables.googleusercontent.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=
SELECT name FROM 3427749 
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS('geometry',RECTANGLE(LATLNG(32.618591,-115.441528),LATLNG(31.954109,-115.212509)))
```

and return *void* but if you try paint the same coordinates in a rectangle you can see it well and if you look the table, this region contains valid coordinates for my query.

Painting the same region:

---

```
 var boudns = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(32.618591, -115.441528),    new google.maps.LatLng(31.954109,-115.212509));

 var rectOptions = {
          strokeColor: "#000000",
          strokeOpacity: 0.6,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: "#000000",
          fillOpacity: 0.2,
          bounds: boudns
        };
 rect.setOptions(rectOptions);

 var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.926013,-101.90918),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

 rect.setMap(map);

//You need implement a div with id map_canvas and put the code in `<script>` tags.
```

---

What is wrong? Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your latitudes wrong in your search RECTANGLE.

From the [FT SELECT Reference Docs](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference#Select)

```
The syntax is: RECTANGLE(<lower_left_corner>, <upper_right_corner>)
```

You have:

```
ST_INTERSECTS('geometry',RECTANGLE(LATLNG(32.618591,-115.441528),LATLNG(31.954109,-115.212509)))
```

Latitude 32.618591 > 31.954109
When I switched these latitudes and ran your query I got one name "Mexicali - El Faro"

Comment: Many thanks, all this work don't let me think well. Thank to you i can finish my tesis JIT.  Greetings +++KARMA